# How to get a range of a body being shot\thrown? Theoretical question.

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I already asked a similar question here, but the answers were technical, leading me to no genuine comprehension of what I am doing.(I am not complaining or anything, I really thanked you then.) Suppose I throw a stone in a straight direction with an initial velocity. What is the range of my throwing? I have a starting point, a velocity, and an acceleration, that is the gravity. I suppose my acceleration is negative in that case. Looking for the range, should I be looking at the point when the velocity is zero? That point has a time and place, but I am not sure how to really compute "range". I could really appreciate your explanation on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Try to visualize the motion of the body separately along the 2 axes X and Y. Write the equations of motion with constant acceleration and you should have solvable equations for the height and velocity of the body. Try to think of the range of the body as the x component of the distance it travels when y increases from 0 and goes back to 0 as the height increases and then decreases.

Comment: Shouldn't the range refer only the parts where the body is progressing? (Not regressing, like falling.)

Comment: It can only progress forward as long as it's "in flight." The moment it hits the ground, your equations stop working. Thus, you need to consider both the $x$ and $y$ displacement. Notably, you want to see how far the object  travels in $x$ while its height above ground is greater than $y=0$, assuming $0$ is the height of the ground.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you present. I shall try it now and let you know if there are still any misunderstanding. .

Comment: @TheMagicalMachine , What if this is a cannonball? 
Is it still okay to look at range that way?

Comment: @meitar It depends on whether you take into account air resistance or not. If you assume a frictionless environment then the same equations will work for any object with a given initial velocity vector and position.

Comment: You should be fine as long as it is a rigid body. Ideally it should be a particle but due to properties of center of mass, this applies to rigid bodies as well

Comment: If I may ask, if I throw a body in a direction of $60$ degrees with a velocity of 80 m\s, how can I write it as an (x,y)? If I threw it upwards, it would merely be $v_0=(0,80)$. I am so baffled.

Comment: You can resolve the velocity along x and y directions by taking the cos and sine components of the velocity. For instance, if a body is thrown at an angle $\theta$ (with the horizontal) with a velocity $v$, then $v_x = vcos(\theta)$ and $v_y = vsin(\theta)$

Comment: You've been very helpful. Thank you.